# Can't deselect all options in a multi select field on Chrome/Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, multi-select

Very simple example:

```
<select id="multi" multiple="multiple">
  <option selected="selected">Option 0</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("multi").options[0].selected = false;
</script>
```

In the desktop version of Chrome, no options are selected after the code has run. In the Android version (tested on a Nexus 7 with Android 4.4.2), the first option is still selected. It seems that Chrome interprets "multiple" selection as "at least one". Does anyone know of a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Probably script is not enabled in your browser

Comment: JavaScript is enabled. I can use options[1].selected = true, for example.

Comment: Probably script is not enabled in your browser. Its working quite fine in my browser. jsfiddle would work fine. See this http://jsfiddle.net/johirbuet/j9J5m/

Comment: Did you test this in Chrome on Android? Like I said, it works fine in the desktop version for me as well. I can't verify your jsFiddle example because Chrome on Android gets confused by the iframe and won't open the menu when I tap the select element.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in Chrome for Android (version 30). After updating to the latest version (35), deselecting the option works as expected.